# Connect dots function

Tags: r

I am learning cross validation method.
In the lines below, the input and query are both a data frame.

```
my.knn <- get.knnx(input,query,k=2)
nn.index <- my.knn$nn.index
```

What does the second line mean? What will `nn.index` be?

Comment: Hi @Hayward Li, did the answer below help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`my.knn` is a list of variables. So `nn.index` is taking that value out of the list so you can work on it as a single variable.

**EXAMPLE OF GETTING ELEMENTS OUT OF A LIST**

```
stats <- list("mean" = 10, "data" = c(0, 10 ,20))

#just get the average out
my.average <- stats$mean
```

So a list can have different kind of results from your testing, and can have a mix of variable types (integers, strings, vectors). The $ syntax is taking one of the variables out of the list into a single variable.

If you type `my.knn` at the prompt you will see its contents with sections marked with $. This will help see what is in your list.

In the example:

```
> stats
$mean
[1] 10

$data
[1]  0 10 20
```

**SPECIFICS ON FUNCTION**

I looked at `get.knnx` function notes, assuming you are using FNN package, here http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/fnn/docs/get.knn:

> Output a list contains:
>
> *nn.index*
>
> an n x k matrix for the nearest neighbor indice(s).
>
> *nn.dist*
>
> an n x k matrix for the nearest neighbor Euclidean distances.

So you can see your function output list has these two variables - an index of the nearest neighbour, and the second is the distances.

Trust this helps.

Comment: P.S. I don't know what cross validation package you are using, so I cant tell you exactly what `get.knnx` does. View its help by entering `?get.knnx` at the prompt, when you package is loaded with `library(packagename)`, to see what its output is.

Comment: Your answer is really helpful to me. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green. You get rep as well.